# How to search non-Android Java projects on GitHub?

Tags: java, android, github, filter

There are always so many Android libs/repos
when we want to search for Java libs/repos.

GitHub docs tells we could use filters
but there is no out-of-the-box examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `NOT` filter:

```
{lib-name} NOT android language:java
```

Example:

[audio player NOT android language:java](https://github.com/search?q=audio+player+NOT+android+language%3Ajava&type=Repositories)

More filter usages:

- [Understand the search syntex - GitHub Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax) ([中文](https://docs.github.com/cn/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax))